# Image not found on lookup

Tags: flipkart-api

I am trying to use lookup class fetching product data. But image I am getting with API response its says 404 not found.

Here are URL what I'm getting in "imageUrls" tag with key "unknown"

```
http://img.fkcdn.com/image/mobile/x/b/z/motorola-moto-g5-plus-xt-1686-800-imaes3bg4tfyfc2v.jpeg
```

Please check out...

Now I don't have anything to type here so I'm just writing this line remove if anyone found it...
Its not giving me access post my question

Answer (score 1):

**This is bug of FlipKart API**

Please use this link as :

http://img.fkcdn.com/image/mobile/x/b/z/motorola-moto-g5-plus-xt-1686-800X800-imaes3bg4tfyfc2v.jpeg

Replace 800 => 800x800 OR 400X400 OR 200X200 (width & height)

My suggestion : Please use v.01 Api
https://affiliate-api.flipkart.net/affiliate/1.0/search.json